# During Hydra OAuth 2.0 integration facing Error : “Client authentication failed”

Tags: docker, authentication, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, ory-hydra

We are using ORY Hydra for oAuth 2 and OpenId connection using Docker.

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.ory.sh/run-oauth2-server-open-source-api-security/) to configuring OAuth 2.0 on the server. I get the 404 Error when I check the log than find out the error which is

[image]

I have applied the Docker code which displayed in the tutorial, then also I get a 404 Error from 0.0.0.0:9000 port.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Thanks for the editing the question if you have an answer then please provide us.

Comment: It's probably a bit too brief to answer. Perhaps you can show the code in the question itself (the link is insufficient).